# Ways to share files between 6 VMs

Tags: debian, vps, file-sharing

I own 6 Virtual Machines that need to access each other's files. The way I've been doing it now is by making a symlink of each file that needs to be shared in the web directory and using POST and PHP to keep some of the files secure.

Is there a better way to do this though? Is there a better way to gain read or even write access to my other machines without installing a webserver on each one? Perhaps even a link that can point to a file on another server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not indicated the OS, distribution and versions of all the 6 Virtual machines you want to share files with....thus I'll assume that they are all Linux.

I'd suggest using a filesystem mounted on one VM exported using NFS.  The other clients would have the mounted via NFS the exported filesystem (or actually dirctory for that matter) from the one VM.  Thus you have what you want.

Comment: Sorry, all of the machines are running Debian. Does the default filesystem work?

Comment: you cannot use a native filesystem mounted over those six vms...NO.

Comment: Which filesystem would you recommend for this?

Comment: The "master" can mount whateveer filesystem type you wish, the sharing comes from the NFS mechanism.  So...ext4 is always a good choice unless you have another favorite.